# INNER JOIN sql

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` INNER JOIN `users` ON users.vk_id = notifications.from WHERE notifications.to = '$user_vk_id' OR notifications.from = '$user_vk_id'");
```

Мне нужно ещё создать ON users.vk_id = notifications.to. Примерно так:

```
ON users.vk_id = notifications.from ON users.vk_id = notifications.to
```

Но как правильно написать, я не догоняю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND вместо второго ON

Comment: @minamoto, а теперь как понять где from, а где to? Он выводит что-то одно. Пример http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1353443408-clip-1kb.png

Comment: @minamoto, точнее он почему-то выводит половину материалов теперь.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю тогда, что надо. Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы понятно, что вы хотите получить, а не что сделать. Потому что "Мне нужно ещё создать ON users.vk_id = notifications.to" - это неправильный вопрос, вам это не нужно.
Можно еще попробовать так, может это надо:
SELECT * FROM `notifications` INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.vk_id = notifications.to WHERE notifications.to = '$user_vk_id' OR notifications.from = '$user_vk_id'

Comment: @minamoto, Вы однозначно рулите!

Comment: @minamoto Только не AND, а OR (в исходном тексте поменять одну букву)

Иначе получится уведомление от самого себя самому себе. "Тихо сам с собою я веду беседу"

Comment: Или

    ON users.vk_id in (notifications.from, notifications.to)